# Why heat conductivity increases when fluids move in opposite directions?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

All heat exchangers are designed such that if, per example, steam to be codensed is coming from the right, cooling water is coming from the left and that increases heat transfer.

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rate of heat transfer depends on temperature difference.

If the flows are opposite directions; it means the hot side first contacts the warmed up cold side; while the cold side first contacts the cooled down hot side.

This keeps the temperature difference ($\Delta T$) approximately the same, instead of having it start high and end low.  This means the amount of heat transferred is about the same at every point.

Comment: I understand what you've said here, but I don't think you've answered "Why heat conductivity increases when fluids move in opposite directions?"  Perhaps the OP's question is a false premise?  Also, what is the advantage of having delta T approximately the same along the length?  Is it to minimize thermal stresses?

Comment: @James I answered the question in the body.  I don't think the overall heat transfer would directly change from that; but I'm also blanking on the specific reason they design for uniform heat transfer.  So I'm reluctant to say it doesn't change it overall.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter whether the flows are cocurrent or countercurrent if you are dealing with saturated steam at constant temperature and pressure on one side.  But if you have two fluids in which the hot fluid gets colder and the cold fluid gets hotter, if you work it out with heat balances, the average temperature driving force is higher if you run countercurrent, and the heat transfer area is lower.